# Onclicklistener with RecycleView with the same Design after click on one item

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

i need to use `Adaptor` after this question: [Implementing an RecycleView or CardView items with the same design for eachother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682580/implementing-an-recycleview-or-cardview-items-with-the-same-design-for-eachother)

But, there is a problem with implemention this.Here is my **MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TITLES[] = {"Home", "My Account", "Help", "About"};
    int ICONS[] = {R.drawable.ic_home, R.drawable.acc, R.drawable.ic_help, R.drawable.ic_about};
    String NAME = "Hi user!";
    int PROFILE = R.drawable.ic_account;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    //items
    RecyclerView recycle2;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager rec2lay;
    DrawerLayout Drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //FOR each item
        recycle2 = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recycle2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);
        recycle2.setLayoutManager(rec2lay);
        adapter = new CardAdapter();
        recycle2.setAdapter(adapter);
                                            //try debuging
                //Codes for MainRecycle view
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,PROFILE,this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }
        };
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And i'm using this adaptor for Showing Recycleview in the **mainLayout:**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<NatureItem> mItems;

    public CardAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<NatureItem>();
        NatureItem nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("The Great Barrier Reef");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
                      "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.great_barrier_reef);
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Grand Canyon");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
                "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.grand_canyon);
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Baltoro Glacier");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
                "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.baltoro_glacier);
        mItems.add(nature);

        nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Iguazu Falls");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
                "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.ig);
        mItems.add(nature);


        nature = new NatureItem();
        nature.setName("Aurora Borealis");
        nature.setDes("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt" +
                      "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.");
        nature.setThumbnail(R.drawable.aurora_borealis);
        mItems.add(nature);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        NatureItem nature = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvNature.setText(nature.getName());
        viewHolder.tvDesNature.setText(nature.getDes());
        viewHolder.imgThumbnail.setImageResource(nature.getThumbnail());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView imgThumbnail;
        public TextView tvNature;
        public TextView tvDesNature;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgThumbnail = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
            tvNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_nature);
            tvDesNature = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des_nature);
        }
    }
}
```

From this good tutorial: http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/cardview/custom-android-list.html

And here is my adaptor to try when user clicked on One item in above item(**5 item actually)** user going to another activity(called: items_recycleview in my app) with the same design for each item(five item) but, with the different picture and different name in this activity:

**ItemsAdaptor:**

```
public class ItemsAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdaptor.PersonViewHolder> {

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
    List<Person> persons;

    ItemsAdaptor(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
        }
    }

}
```

So, how we can achive this and what we need to do?

Here is the Log Error after doing this :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference
            at com.test.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

it seems, there is an error in the`android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)`

Whats the problem?

**Edit:** MainActivty layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

And, **items_recycleview**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cv"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_photo"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/person_age"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/person_photo"
                android:layout_below="@+id/person_name"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How to fix and doing this ?

Something like whatsapp contacts or Telegram contacts, when you are clicking on one item of contact, it show us same design, but, with Different numbers or different picture.and at the designs, nothing changed.

Thanks

Comment: Try removing this line `mRecyclerView = new RecyclerView(this);` from your onCreate() method.

Comment: same error, App crashed again.

Comment: You're setting mRecyclerView twice. First you do `mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);` and then again `mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);` . Why is that? What does your layout file look like?

Comment: I think, because i'm using navigation drawer from  : `http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-navigation-drawer.html` check my question.i have edited the question and added the main layout.

Comment: I can't find a RecyclerView with an id of `R.id.rv` in your layout file but you've used it in your code. Where do you have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have 3 RecyclerViews in your layout files, you'll need to create 3 RecyclerView variables. Right now you're assigning two RecyclerViews to the same variable called `mRecylcerView`. Create a new RecyclerView variable where you're creating the other ones and use that instead. For example:

```
RecyclerView recycle3;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter2;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager rec3lay;
```

Comment: Did you get the same problems? You need to use the new variable inside your code too. Did you do that?